# Google Maps/Places API javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am a CIS student at UT Tyler. I'm working on a project for a class that may seem simple to many. Unfortunately, I am a bit confused at the moment and I'm in need of some assistance if possible.

The project I am currently working on is a web app that allows the user to input a city and state, or a zip code and will upon clicking "search" bring up both local photos and videos.

The part I am having difficulty with is the last bit. I have looked at the maps and places api for Google, but I am unsure how to incorporate them into my html/javascript code so that it functions properly.

How do I get it to bring up just the photos and videos of whatever the user searches. I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: You could look up on youtube videos for tutorials how to add a marker in google map. This is not right place to ask how to code until you post a code saying what is wrong with this code.

Comment: You picked a pretty advanced topic for someone who is new to programming, the google api's expect that you have a relatively strong knowledge of programming already under your belt and are not friendly to newcomers. As Ivan suggested I would see if there is any help on Youtube on how to get started with the Google Places API and/or Google Maps API first and come back with you have questions regarding the code that you have already written.

Comment: Start with the docs: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro and break it down to what you need to do. Right now your question isn't specific enough as to what actual part you are having issues with. Is it when to call the place api call or how to implement the search?